# Stopping a Shiny app in a Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: r, shiny, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a shiny app in a Bitbucket repo and I'd like to run then stop the app in the pipeline. My `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: rocker/verse:3.5.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
        - cd /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
        - Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("shiny", "googleAuthR", "dplyr", 
          "googleAnalyticsR", "knitr", "rmarkdown", "jsonlite"), 
          repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/")'
        - Rscript -e 'shiny::runApp(appDir = file.path("/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/", "app"))'
        - Rscript -e 'shiny::stopApp()'
```

Everything loads and runs successfully but the final line never runs; the pipeline sits on the `shiny::runApp()` command:

[image]

The pipeline will just let the app run until I stop the pipeline manually.

How can I force the final `shiny::stopApp()` to run and close the app thus finishing the pipeline?

Comment: Can you run it using `&` ? Looks like your process would be stuck on the runapp command.

Comment: Stuck on `runApp()`, exactly. How would I add the `stopApp()` command with `&`?

Comment: You would want to append the `&` in the run app command so it runs in the background rather than in your current process. For more explanation -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the run app command to:

`- Rscript -e 'shiny::runApp(appDir = file.path("/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/", "app"))' &`

This would start the run app command in a separate process.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Note you might have to incorporate some sort of feedback command since you might theoretically stop it before it has started.

Comment: I ended up adding a `sleep 10` command to force the `shiny::stopApp()` command to wait a bit to ensure the Shiny app is actually running. Thanks again!